# How to prevent an if condition from executing until readdir finishes in nodejs/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, fs

```
app.get('/students/:record_id', function (req, res) {
  var found =false;
  var record_id = req.params.record_id;
  var dirname = "students/";


  filenames = fs.readdirSync(dirname);
  filenames.forEach(filename => {
    
    fs.readFile(dirname + filename, "utf-8", function (err, data ) {
      if (err) {
        onError(err);
        return;
      }
      if (data.includes(record_id)) {
        found = true;
        return res.status(200).send(data);
        
      }
    });
  });

  if(found == false){ 
    return res.status(500).send({ "message": "error - no student found" });
  }

});
```

I am using GET searching by a student name to retrieve a students file. If I remove the if condition it is successful. But if the student does not exist then it does not work.
The if condition fixes this by making found true when it finds it in the file. The problem is that the if condition executes before the file is read.
I tried using a callback but after a couple hours of research I can not figure out how to implement it in this since the readfile callback is being used to retrieve student info.

I tried using a promise but the promise is then only fulfilled if the student is found and I do not know how to implement it where it is fulfilled when it is not found.

Comment: `I tried using a promise` that's how I'd do it, reject on error, or reject if the forEach doesn't "complete"

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am new to javascript so I am not used to thinking about functions running in asynch,  @Bravo

Comment: I was just about to post an answer and the question gets closed

Comment: So, here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SsLQRvc8) for you

Comment: No problems. that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call link is way over used as a duplicate and has such a wall of information in the answer it probably scares people rather than helps :p (IMNSHO)

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't use 500 status for student not found - unless a student not found really is an "internal server error" - which is what 500 indicates

Comment: unfortunately it still does not run @Bravo

Comment: looking closely, I've made a mistake ... it should be (I think) `import fs from 'fs/promises'` - but that would mean ALL `fs.` calls will return a Promise - so, not sure how that would effect code you didn't show (if you use `require` ... then you'll need to make the necessary adjustments)

Comment: @bravo re opened

Comment: Thanks @Keith - while the duplicate is valid, there's other aspects of the logic that I believe need to be addressed anyway

Comment: what you mean by require. I used const fs = require('fs');
const promise = require('promise'); @Bravo

Comment: `require("fs/promises')`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tried with Promises, I'll show you how to do it with Promises

Using async/await especially makes this really easy

Note: since I don't know how you are using `fs` the import/require only gets the promise versions of readdir and readFile, and uses it like `readdir` rather than `fs.readdir` - so other existing code won't break

```
const {readFile, readdir} = require('fs/promises');

// if you use import (modules) instead of require (commonjs)
// import { readFile, readdir } from 'fs/promises';

app.get('/students/:record_id', async function (req, res) {
    var record_id = req.params.record_id;
    var dirname = "students/";

    try {
        const filenames = await readdir(dirname);
        for (let filename of filenames) {
            const data = await readFile(dirname + filename, "utf-8");
            if (data.includes(record_id)) {
                return res.status(200).send(data);
            }
        }
        res.status(404).send({"message": "error - student not found"});
    } catch (err) {
        onError(err);
        res.status(500).send({"message": "internal server error"});
    }
});
```

Note: I wouldn't send a 500 (Internal Server Error) if a student is not found - I changed the logic to send 404 (not Found) instead - which is more appropriate

If you want pure promise (no async/await) - I believe the following is one way to do it, probably not the nicest code, but it should work (haven't tested though)

```
const {readFile, readdir} = require('fs/promises');

// if you use import (modules) instead of require (commonjs)
// import { readFile, readdir } from 'fs/promises';

app.get('/students/:record_id', function (req, res) {
    var record_id = req.params.record_id;
    var dirname = "students/";
    
    let p = Promise.resolve(false);
    for (let filename of filenames) {
        p = p
        .then(found => 
            found ? found : readFile(dirname + filename, "utf-8")
            .then(
                data => 
                    data.includes(record_id) ? data : false
            )
        );
    }
    .then(data => data ? res.status(200).send(data) : res.status(404).send({"message": "error - student not found"}))
    .catch(err => {
        onError(err);
        res.status(500).send({"message": "internal server error"});
    })
});
```

And, finally - without using Promises at all

```
app.get('/students/:record_id', function (req, res) {
    let found = false;
    const record_id = req.params.record_id;
    const dirname = "students/";

    const filenames = fs.readdirSync(dirname);
    const count = filenames.length;
    const checkFile = index => {
        if (index < count) {
            const filename = filenames[index];
            fs.readFile(dirname + filename, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    onError(err);
                    res.status(500).send({"message": "internal server error"});
                } else if (data.includes(record_id)) {
                    res.status(200).send(data);
                } else {
                    checkFile(index + 1)
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({"message": "error - student not found"});
        }
    }
    checkFile(0);
});
```

Comment: So when testing it I get onError is not defined. I removed this but when testing a name that exists and one that does not, I only get internal server error

Comment: I also get a warning that const filenames  is not being used.

Comment: typos - sorry - hang on - npot sure why `onError` is not defined ... it's not defined in YOUR code either - the missing `s` in `filename of filename` probably threw an error (it would)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these methods are working even with the typo fixes

Comment: For the first method, I see you have the await but where is the promise being made and fulfilled?

Comment: `readdir` and `readFile` return a Promises - fullfilled on success, rejected on error - that's what the promise versions of `fs` do .... to be clear, `const {readFile, readdir} = require('fs/promises');` returns versions of fs methods that return promises - hence why there's `/promises` in the module name

Comment: @JaroldSabillon - FYI, I added code that doesn't use promises at all if that makes you more comfortable